# Counter example for $\overline{E \cap F} \subset \overline{E} \cap \overline{F}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I found a proof for this, but I don't quite understand one part of it.

Let X be a real number line under the Euclidean topology.

> Let $H_1 = [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ and $H_2 = [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Then $\overline{H_1} \cup \overline{H_2} = \frac{1}{2} $. It follows that $\overline{H_1 \cap H_2} \neq \overline{H_1} \cap \overline{H_2}$

Isn't $\overline{H_1 \cap H_2}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ as well? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: The statement doesnt make sense, or maybe Im not understanding something. Observe that $[0,\frac12]$ is already closed. The union of the closed sets is $[0,1]$. In any case it cant be a number as $\frac12$, because a number is not a subset of the real line.

Comment: @Masacroso Yeah, which is why I was fairly confused. I got the counter example off of wiki. It's here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Intersection_may_not_equal_Intersection_of_Closures if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a typo. It sounds like the example is trying to find $H_1, H_2$ such that $\overline{H_1\cap H_2} \neq \overline{H_1}\cap \overline{H_2}$. In this case, choosing open intervals (instead of closed intervals) $H_1=(0,\frac12)$ and $H_2=(\frac12,1)$ gives $\overline{H_1\cap H_2}=\emptyset$ while $\overline{H_1}=[0,\frac12]$ and $\overline{H_2}=[\frac12,1]$ so $\overline{H_1}\cap \overline{H_2} = \{\frac12\}.$

Comment: Oh thank you so much. It makes so much sense now! But wouldn't this example give $\neq$ since you get $\emptyset$ and $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{H_1\cap H_2} \subsetneq \overline{H_1}\cap \overline{H_2}$ means $\overline{H_1\cap H_2} \subseteq \overline{H_1}\cap \overline{H_2}$ and $\overline{H_1\cap H_2} \neq \overline{H_1}\cap \overline{H_2}$. Edited for clarity

Comment: A maybe more picturesque example is $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.